# Sequentially process Messages from ServiceActivators to multiple outbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-integration

We have this following simple requirement for which we are using Spring Integration:

1. Poll few DB tables for incoming tasks (rows with `status=1`)
2. Process each row from the above rows and update multiple tables say `A, B and C`.

   1. These update may be **sequential** and **dependent**, i.e `B` and `C` should be updated after `A` is persisted since that info will be needed later.
   2. Following are the constraints on `B` and `C`: `B` will use the id of `A` plus the info from rows found using the poll.
3. Set the `status` flag in step 1. to `0`

What we have till now:

1. `inbound-channel-adapter` for polling Step 1.

   ```
   <int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter channel="inboundWFOne"
               entity-manager="entityManagerFactory"
               jpa-query="select en from WorkflowOne en where en.status=1"
               delete-after-poll="true">
   <int:poller>
       <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
        <!-- Note: This is not working for us.. hence the delete-after-poll for timebeing <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED" transaction-manager="transactionManager" synchronization-factory="txSyncFactory"/>-->
   </int:poller>
   </int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>
   ```
2. The Service activator that will return a `List<Message<?>>` since it will be combination of `A`, `B` and `C` entities.

   ```
    <int:service-activator input-channel="inboundWFOne" ref="wfOneService"
               method="processWFOne" output-channel="outboundWFOne" />
   ```
3. We were thinking of a `<int:chain>` with a `<int:payload-type-router>` which will route `A`, `B` and `C` to different channels and there will be `outbound-channel-adapter`s there which will write to DB. <s>However there is no guarantee of the order with design!</s>
   How do we form the chain, such that after `A` is persisted we pass the `id` back so `B` and `C` can use it. Basically satisfy the conditions in 2.2 above.

Note: The `int:jpa`'s `outbound-channel-adapter` does not seem to have any way to pass back the persisted object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is. If you don't have any thread shifting, everything is performed sequential in the same thread. So, that your `List<Message<?>>` is iterated and the item is send to the router's channel. The router knows where to send this message further -to the appropriate Outbound Channel Adapter for saving. And only after save the call is returned to the loop mentioned in the beginning to process the next message.

So, only what you need to ensure is the proper order in that list of messages from that service activator.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, addition to the sequential write to DB, we need id generated in step 1 for later steps. So in the `chain` is there a way for `B` and `C` to wait for `A` to persist first? So then we pass the `id` of `A` to `B` and `C` ?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, missed that part. So, yes you need a Gateway on that case. Even if you will use it for the B and C you can just ignore the reply. This way when you send A you will use return for the next iteration. I'd even suggest to do that manually from the service activator and don't do any return `List<Message<?>>`. Yes, I think you should use for that purpose JPA Updating Gateway: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.html#jpa-updating-outbound-gateway